# postconf -d not updating after service postfix reload

Tags: postfix

I am trying to update postfix main.cf using the commands,

```
postconf -ev disable_vrfy_command=yes
service postfix reload
```

but when I check postconf -d I still get disable_vrfy_command=no.  I also tried restarting postfix and editing main.cf, and still the same issue.  Any ideas why this might be happening?

I am running the command as root

Comment: I too need an answer to this ... did you discover a solution ?

Answer (score 5):

Use this command to check the current parameter values in the configuration:

```
postconf -p
```

Or just:

```
postconf
```

The command that you have used with the `-d` option will print the **default** values. You can also use the `-n` option to print only the **non-default** values, to print only what you explicitly changed in the `main.cf` configuration. See the [Ubuntu Manpage on postconf](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/postconf.1.html) for even more options.

Although this question was posted over a year ago, I am curious where you might have read instructions to use the `-d` option, because you are not the only one walking into this problem.

Comment: No, most definitely not the only one. I've been using it for hours (in 2022!) until I stumbled upon _this_ question here...